# How to create two HierarchicalDataTemplates which are mutually-referential in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Given that:

1. DataTemplates cannot be assigned by TargetType

   StaticResource references can only reference previously

How does one template the following situation in a TreeView?

```
class Resource {
  public string Name {get;}
  public IEnumerable<Property> Properties {get;}
}

class Property {
  public string Name {get;}
  public IEnumerable<Resource> Values {get;}
}
```

That structure lends itself well to a tree which would look like:

```
Resource 1
|- Property A
   | - Resource 2
   | - Resource 3
|- Property B
   |- Resource 4
```

This would trivial to template in WPF because of the `TargetType` property of `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.  In Silverlight, we would have to do something more like:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ResourceTemplate"
                          ItemSource="{Binding Properties}"
                          ItemTemplate={StaticResource PropertyTemplate}" />

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="PropertyTemplate"
                          ItemSource="{Binding Values}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceTemplate}" />
```

Which obviously can't work because `ResourceTemplate` can't reference `PropertyTemplate` because it is defined after it in the XAML document.  So, how do you solve this chicken-and-egg problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable solution I've found is to create a third ViewModel type which would wrap either of the first two types (Resource or Property) and provide common properties to bind to: (e.g. children).  This still is not very optimal, though, if the two types need very different templates because at that point, I am using the `VisualStateManager` to switch between templates for the data.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeItemTemplate"
                          ItemSource="{Binding Children}">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
    <VisualStateManager.Groups>
      <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState Name="IsResource">
          <!-- set resource template -->
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState Name="IsProperty">
          <!-- set property template -->
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.Groups>
  </ContentPresenter>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't really answer the question I was trying to ask, which is how can two resources reference each other?